# Arrange strings in alphabetical order

Tags: c#, algorithm, sorting

```
        //code with problem (maybe) 
        numberArray = NameNumEquv;
        listStringArray = NamesArray;
        string[] sortedArray = new string[NamesArray.Length];

        for (int arrayItemCounter = 0; arrayItemCounter < NamesArray.Length; arrayItemCounter++)
        {
            compareArrayCount = 1;
            initialArrayCount = 0;
            while (compareArrayCount < numberArray.Length)
            {
                for (int doubleArrayLength = 0; doubleArrayLength < numberArray[compareArrayCount].Length; doubleArrayLength++)
                {
                    if (numberArray[initialArrayCount][doubleArrayLength] < numberArray[compareArrayCount][doubleArrayLength])
                    {
                        initialArrayCount = compareArrayCount;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                compareArrayCount = compareArrayCount + 1;
            }

            sortedArray[arrayItemCounter] = listStringArray[initialArrayCount];

            List<string> tempArrayValues = new List<string>();
            List<int[]> tempNumArrayValues = new List<int[]>();

            for (int tempArrayCount = 0; tempArrayCount < listStringArray.Length; tempArrayCount++)
            {
                if (tempArrayCount != initialArrayCount)
                {
                    tempArrayValues.Add(listStringArray[tempArrayCount]);
                    tempNumArrayValues.Add(numberArray[tempArrayCount]);
                }
            }

            listStringArray = tempArrayValues.ToArray();
            numberArray = tempNumArrayValues.ToArray();
            tempArrayValues.Clear();
            tempNumArrayValues.Clear();
        }
        //till here
        foreach (string nums in sortedArray)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(nums);
        }
    }

    public static int[] AlphaNumericConversion(string stringValue, int arrayLength) 
    {
        string Alphabets = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        char[] alphabetArray = Alphabets.ToCharArray();

        string lowerCaseConv = stringValue.ToLower();
        char[] stringArray = lowerCaseConv.ToCharArray();

        int[] numericalConvertedArray = new int[arrayLength];
        for (int valueArrayCount = 0; valueArrayCount < numericalConvertedArray.Length; valueArrayCount++)
        {
            numericalConvertedArray[valueArrayCount] = 0;
        }

        for (int letterCounter= 0;letterCounter < stringArray.Length;letterCounter++)
        {
            for (int alphabetCounter = 0; alphabetCounter < Alphabets.Length; alphabetCounter++)
            {
                if (stringArray[letterCounter] == alphabetArray[alphabetCounter])
                    numericalConvertedArray[letterCounter] = alphabetCounter + 1;
            }
        }

        return numericalConvertedArray;
    }
  }
}
```

I want to arrange strings in ascending order. It is arranging the single letter strings(a, b, c,d, e.....) in reverse alphabetical order as in Z-A and string containing 2 or more letters randomly such as "Aayush", "Ayush", "Aayusha", "Ayusha" to "Aayusha","Ayusha","Aayush","Ayush". What is wrong with the code. Don't suggest to simply use List.Sort() because I want to write it in algorithmic manner. I'm trying to understand how it works rather than using Sort().

Comment: Could you provide some examples, please, since "arranging the single letter strings in reverse alphabetical order and string containing 2 or more letters randomly" means some custom sort, not lexicographical one

Comment: I edited it so you can understand it better.

Comment: Please check the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a good question. In particular, the part on how to create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It is much more likely to get answers if you limit the work for potential answerers by leaving out all irrelevant code.